# Error in Nested Resources in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My routes.rb

```
resources :post do
      resources :answers do
        resources :anscomments
      end
    end
```

models

**post.rb**

```
has_many :answers
```

**answer.rb**

```
belongs_to :post
has_many :anscomments
```

**anscomment.rb**

```
belongs_to :answer
```

controller

**answers_controller.rb**

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @answer = @post.answers.create(params[:answer])
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

**anscomments_controller.rb**

```
class AnscommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
    @anscomment = @answer.anscomments.create(params[:anscomment])
    redirect_to post_path(@answer)
  end
end
```

views

**view/post/show.html.erb**

```
<table align=center width="60%" bordercolor="black">

    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <h2>
                <%=@post.title%> 
            </h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <h3><%=@post.body%></h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            This Post comes under:<%=@post.tag%>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<br />
<h2 align="center">Answers</h2>
<div align="center">
    <% @post.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <table width="50%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <%= answer.body %>
            </td>
        </tr>



        <div align="center">
            <% @answer.anscomments.each do |anscomment| %>
            <table width="40%" %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%= anscomment.body %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <%end%>
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <%= form_for([@answer,@answer.anscomments.build]) do |f| %>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= f.text_area :body %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= f.submit "Submit Comment" %></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <%end%>
        </div>



    </table>
    <% end %>
</div>
<br />
<h2 align="center">Your Answer</h2>
<div align="center">
    <%= form_for([@post, @post.answers.build]) do |f| %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><%= f.text_area :body %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%= f.submit "Post Your Answer" %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

when i tried to click on individual post i am getting an error like----"undefined method `anscomments' for nil:NilClass"

please find a solution.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `answer.anything` instead of `@answer.anything` in `post/show.html.erb`

```
<%= answer.body %>
```

is correct,

```
<% @answer.anscomments.each do |anscomment| %>
```

error, @answer is not initialized (nil)

Comment: You have created instance variable @post in your controller and used it in the view. But `@answer` instance variable is not defined (nil). Instead, you created local variable `answer` in `<% @post.answers.each do |answer| %>` block. So you should refer to `answer`, not to `@answer`. Take a look at your view, `<%= answer.body %>` does not generate error, but `<% @answer.anscomments.each do |anscomment| %>` does.

Comment: so where i should create the @answer instance variable ......please specify the controller also..

Comment: You should not, just use `answer` instead of '@answer`